# Change value of slider without notifying listener

Tags: matlab, events, listener, matlab-guide

I am creating a GUI with GUIDE and have added a slider to my GUI. Afterwards, I have added a listener to my slider

```
myListener = addlistener(handles.mySlider,'Value','PostSet',@(src,evnt)myCallback(src,evnt, handles.figure1));
```

In the function `myCallback` I do some changes to an object I plot on an axis. I also made this object selectable such that another callback is called once the user clicks on the object. I would now like to initialize the slider with the appropriate value for the object just having been selected, but without calling the function `myCallback`.

That is, I need something like

```
setWithoutCallingListener(handles.mySlider, ValueOfSelectedObject);
```

Is that possible?

Comment: The usual way would be to initialize first, then add a listener.

Comment: well that would mean i need to remove the listeners, intialize and add them again every time I select a different object. The sliders are valid for all objects displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to temporarily deactivate a listener is by adding a flag to the handles structure. 
For example, at the beginning of your initialization routine, you set `handles.isInitializing=true; guidata(hObject,handles);`,and add `if handles.isInitializing, return; end` to the beginning of the listener callbacks. Remember to set the flag to `false` at the end of the initialization routine.

Alternatively, don't use listeners, but instead have all UI-element callbacks call a function `updateUI(handles)` (in addition to potential input checking; for example you may want to ensure that the slider can only take on integer values) which takes care of (1) adjusting all interdependent values (e.g. if you have a slider and an edit text box that need to be synced), and of (2) spawning whatever process you need to update the plot. This has the advantage that the UI element callbacks do not fire if you modify the element via a function.

Comment: Thanks Jonas, I ended up using the first way you mentioned.